# Find co-occurrences in python Dictionaries or Dataframes

Tags: python, dictionary, pandas

I have two dictionaries (that can easily be converted to dataframes if needed) and i want find the co-occurrences(friends) of names in them.The first dictionary contains relations between names.

my_dict:

```
{'George': ['Bill','Mary'],
'Bill': ['George'],
'Sam' : [],
....}
```

the other dictionary contains lists of people that went out together

my_dict2:

```
{1: 'Mary,George,Sandra,Alice',
 2: 'Bob,Bill,Sam,George',
 3: 'Simon,Frank',
 ....}
```

I want to find a list/dictionary/dataframe of friends that were out together. So an expected output would be:

```
Mary,George
Bill,George
..
```

I tried this

```
for key, my_dict_values in my_dict.items():
    for my_dict2_values in my_dict2.values():
        if key == my_dict2_values and my_dict_values == my_dict2_values :
        ....
```

but it is not working and it takes a lot of time to give a result. Any suggestions?

Thank you

Comment: You can't compare `if 'George' == 'Mary,George,Sandra,Alice':` (`key == my_dict2_values`) use `in` - `if 'George' in 'Mary,George,Sandra,Alice':`

Answer (score 1):

This code is pretty slow (`O(n^3)`) so consider optimising your data structures to see if you can improve how you access friendship details.

```
d1 = {'George': ['Bill','Mary'],
'Bill': ['George'],
'Sam' : [],
}

d2 = {1: 'Mary,George,Sandra,Alice',
 2: 'Bob,Bill,Sam,George',
 3: 'Simon,Frank',
 }

out = []
for p1, friends in d1.items():
    for friend in friends:
        for party in d2.values():
            if p1 in party and friend in party:
                out.append([p1,friend])

print out
```

Gives:

```
[['Bill', 'George'], ['George', 'Bill'], ['George', 'Mary']]
```

Secondly, try writing code that actually describes what you are doing, because it makes it much easier to understand. For example, consider:

```
for key, my_dict_values in my_dict.items():
    for my_dict2_values in my_dict2.values():
        if key == my_dict2_values and my_dict_values == my_dict2_values :
```

Compared to:

```
for p1, friends in d1.items():
    for friend in friends:
        for party in d2.values():
            if p1 in party and friend in party:
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Which data structure do you think will be better?

Comment: Thats a really broad question, and well outside the scope of this one.

Comment: I mean for this task and between dataframe and dictionary